# Codesigning results in process being immediately killed

Tags: c, macos, memory, code-injection

I am trying to manipulate an external process's memory through the mach.h API on MacOS.

The idea is to be able to run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mach/mach_traps.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/mach_error.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    task_t task;
    pid_t pid = argc >= 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1;
    kern_return_t error = task_for_pid(current_task(), pid, &task);
    printf("%d -> %x [%d - %s]\n", pid, task, error, mach_error_string(error));
    return error;
}
```

(after this is able to run using the vm_read/write should be trivial to manipulate memory)

However it seems that Apple has made it increasingly more difficult to use the task_for_pid over the years as it is a system vulnerability. Thankfully (as far as I understand), it has not been made impossible, however I can't seem to get it to work.

After attempting to compile the code using `gcc` and then codesigning it using the following snippet:

```
codesign --sign - \                                    
    --entitlements Entitlements.plist \ 
    --deep main \    
    --force
```

And the Entitlements.plist:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.springboard.debugapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>task_for_pid-allow</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Running the process results in `[1]    <pid> killed     ./main` instantly.
Without the codesign, any PID will simply return `5 - (os/kern) failure` even when run in root.

Does anybody know how to overcome this? Or any other possible solution for accessing foreign processes' memory from C that works as of now (I have found other Stack Overflow questions which answer this, such as [task_for_pid always returns (os/kern) failure on darwin in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659527/task-for-pid-always-returns-os-kern-failure-on-darwin-in-c), but their methods don't seem to work anymore as they are over 10 years old).

I am essentially looking for a ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory equivalent on MacOS.

Any help or further insight is greatly appreciated.